# Haskell creating my own filtering function

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm a new to haskell, I'm trying to create a function that will take a list on integers and returns a list containing two sublists, the first sublist containing the even number and the other containing the odd numbers. I cannot use even, odd or filter functions. i created my own functions as follows

```
myodd :: Integer -> Bool
myodd n = rem (abs(n)) 2 == 1

myeven :: Integer -> Bool
myeven n = rem (abs(n)) 2 == 0

segregate [] = ([], [])
segregate [x] = ([x], [])
segregate (x:y:xs) = (x:xp, y:yp) where (xp, yp) = segregate xs
```

im having trouble trying to use the two first functions and use it on the segregated functions. I have more experience in racket and the function I crated looks like this:

```
    (define (myeven? x)
  (= (modulo x 2) 0)) 

(define (myodd? x)
  (= (modulo x 2) 1))

(define (segregate xs)
  (foldr (lambda (x b)
           (if (myeven? x)
               (list (cons x (first b)) (second b))
               (list (first b) (cons x (second b))))) '(()()) xs))
```

Comment: Your Racket code doesn't make sense. Have you tested it?

Comment: To me, it looks like your Haskell code and your Racket code are doing two very different things - the Racket code partitions the input list depending on whether the *value* is odd or even, whereas the Haskell code partitions the input list depending on whether the *index* of the value is odd or even (errors in the code notwithstanding). Which of the two are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @FrankSchmitt, the Racket code doesn't actually seem to do that. In fact, I'm pretty sure it will throw an error too.

Comment: @dfeuer That's why I wrote 'errors in the code notwithstanding' - to me, it looks like the code is *supposed* to do what I described (I may be mistaken, of course).

Comment: I'm sorry I posted the wrong code. I just fixed (define (myeven? x)
  (= (modulo x 2) 0)) 
 
(define (myodd? x)
  (= (modulo x 2) 1))

(define (segregate xs)
  (foldr (lambda (x b)
           (if (myeven? x)
               (list (cons x (first b)) (second b))
               (list (first b) (cons x (second b))))) '(()()) xs))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way is to run through the list twice using each of your hand-rolled functions as a guard predicate:

```
segregate :: [Integer] -> ([Integer], [Integer])
segregate [] = ([],[])
segregate xs = (evens, odds)
  where evens = [x | x <- xs, myeven x]
        odds  = [x | x <- xs, myodd x]
```

Note: your question asked for a list of lists but your pattern matching `segregate [] = ([],[])` indicated you wanted a tuple so I gave a tuple solution.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I have some problems while compiling the code. It gave a compile error as follows:  Couldn't match expected type ‘Bool’
                with actual type ‘Integer -> Bool’
    Probable cause: ‘myodd’ is applied to too few arguments
    In the expression: myodd
    In a stmt of a list comprehension: myodd

Answer (score 1):

Here's one good way:

```
segregate [] = ?
segregate (x:xs)
  | myEven x = ?
  | otherwise = ?
  where (restEvens, restOdds) = segregate xs
```

You could also use

```
segregate = foldr go ([], []) where
  go x ~(evens, odds)
    | myEven x = ?
    | otherwise = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need such a function rather than writing it for educational purposes, there is `partition` in `Data.List`, so a simple

```
import Data.List(partition)
```

wil get you going.

In the educational case, you can still compare your code, once you're done, with the code of `partition`.